# Is it safe to delete the "$Extend" folder that was backed up from an old hard drive to a new volume?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, ntfs

I recently received a new external hard drive containing data from a failing drive - the data was simply copied from the old, failing drive to the new. At the top level of the drive, I have a folder named "$Extend" - from carrying out some initial research, it appears that this folder is related to the NTFS file system and in the majority of cases isn't visible when viewing directory listings via Windows Explorer.

IN this case, I'm presuming that the presence of this folder is due to the fact that it was copied from the old, failing drive to the new as a regular folder - which is why it's the first time that it's now being detected by Windows Explorer. In this case, is it safe to assume that Windows has created another duplicate (albeit hidden) folder with the same name at the time the replacement drive was formatted - and as a result this folder from the old drive can safely be deleted? I'm aware that typically it's not physically possible to create two files/folders with duplicate names, but am also aware that this is a file system directory - so wasn't sure if it was treated any differently.

Comment: Are you sure the new disk is in fact NTFS and not exFAT?